# Order of Import statements in Angular 2

Tags: angular, convention

The Angular Style Guide says of Import line spacing:

- Consider leaving one empty line between third party imports and
  application imports.
- Consider listing import lines alphabetized by
  the module.
- Consider listing destructured imported symbols
  alphabetically.
- Why? The empty line separates your stuff from their
  stuff.
- Why? Alphabetizing makes it easier to read and locate symbols.

Looking at many Angular projects including Angular itself the convention is to import Angular (`@angular`) modules first, then third-party modules (e.g. AngularFire2) and then our own modules (Services, Components, etc.) e.g. `./some-service.ts`.

Again it looks like it is the convention to import Services, then Models and then Components.

But what about Interfaces and Pipes, etc.? And what is the convention for importing 'nameless' or wildcard modules, e.g. the Firebase SDK or RxJs operators?

For example:

### Example Service that Imports an RxJs Operator

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {
  AngularFireDatabase,
  FirebaseListObservable
} from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
...
```

### Or

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import {
  AngularFireDatabase,
  FirebaseListObservable
} from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
// `GridMetadata` is an Interface
import { GridMetadata } from './grid-metadata';
...
```

Comment: This is not a question for SO. If style guide says nothing on that, it's at your discretion. I personally maintain imports in alphabetic order, core dependencies (@angular and rxjs) go before other third party, first-party go last.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Actually, looking at the Angular codebase and with a better understanding of the guidelines, there is an answer.

### "Consider leaving one empty line between third party imports and application imports."

This just needs an example to explain it:

```
// Core imports
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

// Third party imports
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

// Application imports
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
```

### "Consider listing import lines alphabetized by the module."

Think of the 'modules' as the bit after "from". The modules contain the symbols to be imported.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

It doesn't matter what the symbols are; it is only important that import lines are alphabetised by the module. e.g.

1. angularfire2/auth
2. firebase/app
3. rxjs/Rx
4. rxjs/add/observable/of
5. rxjs/add/operator/catch

In the Angular codebase it is evident that lowercase characters are listed after capitalised or uppercase characters, hence: 'rxjs/Rx' is listed *before* 'rxjs/add/observable/of' and 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'

### "Consider listing destructured imported symbols alphabetically."

```
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

Think of a "destructured imported symbol" as an exported symbol that has been extracted from its parent module. In this example AngularFireAuth, Observable,  TestBed, async and inject are all destructured imported symbols.

Again, the order is alphabetised; uppercase first, then capitalised and then lowercase. Here is a great example from the Angular codebase:

```
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, Compiler, Component, Directive, Inject, Injectable, Injector, Input, NgModule, Optional, Pipe, SkipSelf, ɵstringify as stringify} from '@angular/core';
```

**There doesn't seem to be any particular order to importing services, pipes, models, directives or components, etc. looking at the Angular codebase**

Note, modules in parent directories are imported *after* those closer to the module they are being imported into e.g.

```
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { abc } from '.../abc';
```

Comment: Are there any usable tools to achieve this behaviour automatically?

Comment: @Zozo: Yes, you can give https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/ordered-imports/ a try. It's a rule for tslint to order imports. Something like `"ordered-imports": [ true, { "grouped-imports": true } ]` should be enough in your tslint.json.